# Convert a bunch of png or webp images to a webp animation

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

How to convert a bunch of png or webp images into webp animation ?

I tried this:

```
convert mytiles.png -crop 100x100 +repage tmp.webp
```

But I just get a bunch of webp images instead of an animation.

Another solution would be to use `gif2webp` but the [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/webp) `webp` package doesn't contain this command unlike what's written in the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download).

Comment: I don't think animated Webp is supported https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1111

Comment: Note that using an animated GIF as an intermediate step is not always applicable, as the GIF format is lossy (unless your source images already have indexed colors).

Answer (score 13):

## Convert frames to WebP, then use `webpmux`

The `webpmux` program comes with Google’s reference library for WebP, namely `libwebp`, which you can install through your package manager if not present yet. Its [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/webpmux/) reads:

> `webpmux` — create animated WebP files from non-animated WebP images, extract frames from animated WebP images, and manage XMP/EXIF metadata and ICC profile.

If your individual frames are in another format, you’ll first need to convert them to WebP. For this task you can use ImageMagick (more options [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/webp.php)—be sure to disable [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) unless you want it):

```
convert frame001.png -define webp:lossless=true frame001.webp
```

Then you can combine frames using `webpmux`. The syntax is the following, where the capitalized words are placeholders:

```
webpmux \
  -frame frame001.webp +D1+X1+Y1+M1±b \
  -frame frame002.webp +D2+X2+Y2+M2±b \
  -frame frame003.webp +D3+X3+Y3+M3±b \
  [-loop L]  [-bgcolor A,R,G,B] \
  -o animation.webp
```

Each frame expects a number of settings. All of them but the duration can be left implicit.

- `Di` is the duration of the frame, in milliseconds.
- (`Xi`, `Yi`) is the spatial offset of the frame in the canvas (counting from the top-left corner, X going right and Y going down).
- `Mi` is the *dispose method* for this frame, in other words what to do once this frame has expired. It has two possible values:

  - `0`: do not dispose, leave the canvas as-is;
  - `1`: dispose, *i.e.* clear the canvas and fill it with background (consumes energy, for that matter).
- `±b` is the *blending method* for this frame, which specifies how to superimpose this frame on top of the existing canvas (it is only relevant when the frame has an alpha channel, otherwise it overwrites what is below it anyway). This parameter has two possible values:

  - `-b`: do not blend, the frame overwrites the existing canvas;
  - `+b`: use alpha blending, the frame combines with the existing canvas.

Then come the optional settings that apply to the animation as a whole:

- `-loop L` specifies the number `L` of times to play the animation. You’ll probably want it to be infinite, which is meant by `-loop 0`, which is the default value.
- `-bgcolor A,R,G,B` specifies the background color. The values of the four components (alpha, red, green, blue) range from 0 to 255. Viewers *may* use this color as a background for the canvas, so that the canvas is opaque, but they are not *required* to; in practice the canvas is overlayed on top of other elements, as in a web page for example, and I have not seen this color used.

See also the [WebP specification about animations](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container#animation).

Final tip: since the command line options for each frame are more than just the input file name, you cannot use a wildcard like `frame*.webp` directly and writing the command line proves cumbersome. Thankfully, you can use your shell to build the command line, *e.g* with Bash:

```sh
frames=( )
for f in frame*.webp ; do
    frames+=( -frame "$f" +100+0+0+0+b )
done
webpmux "${frames[@]}" -o animation.webp
```

The example above creates an animation whose frames are all images matching `frame*.webp`, have a duration of 100 ms, have no spatial offset, and combine with the previous frames (use alpha blending for new frames and do not dispose of them afterwards).

Answer (score 2):

You can issue this command to see if your particular convert supports animations for webp:

```
#  convert -list format |grep -i webp
     WEBP* WEBP      rw-   WebP Image Format (libwebp 0.6.1[0208])
```

In this case its convert version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64
And minus in "rw-" means the absence of support for multiple images (within a single file).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Python with the [pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) library to combine individual `.webp`-files into a single animation:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image

INPUT_DIR = Path("/path/to/folder/containing/frames/")
OUTPUT_FILE = Path("/path/to/output.webp")
FRAME_RATE = 30 # frames per second

# Find all '.webp'-files in the input directory and sort them by filename
input_frames = sorted(INPUT_DIR.glob("*.webp"))

# Calculate the duration per frame
frame_duration_ms = round(1000 / FRAME_RATE) # milliseconds

# Load each frame as a PIL.Image object and store it in a list
frames = [Image.open(frame) for frame in input_frames]
# Save the first frame as the output image, with all remaining frames appended
frames[0].save(OUTPUT_FILE, "webp", append_images=frames[1:], duration=frame_duration_ms), save_all=True)
```

This creates the output file as an animated `.webp`.

I haven't tried it explicitly, but PIL can convert between `.png`- and `.webp`-files, so using `.png`-files as the input should work as well.

Comment: could it be that the closing parenthesis after frame_duration_ms is too much?